# Access information of objects inside object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having difficulty  accessing this information in js.

It's an object that has objects inside.

I am getting this information with this:

```
  $preguntas = Question::select('questions.id AS question_id' ,
'questions.date',
 'questions.id_user', 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'questions.views',
 'users.id AS user_id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->toJson();
return $preguntas;
```

And this is the console.log of the $preguntas.

Any ideas?

Many thanks! I am new in php and this is difficult for me.

```
{…}
​
5: {…}
​​
date: "2020-05-17"
​​
description: "awdawd"
​​
first_name: "golfee"
​​
id_user: 131
​​
last_name: "romera"
​​
question_id: 6
​​
title: "awdwad"
​​
user_id: 131
​​
views: 0
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
6: Object { question_id: 7, date: "2020-05-17", id_user: 131, … }
​
7: Object { question_id: 8, date: "2020-05-17", id_user: 131, … }
​
8: Object { question_id: 9, date: "2020-05-17", id_user: 131, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are getting data with PHP and you want to use it with JavaScript?

If so, then you need to convert the PHP data to JSON format, and then read it with JavaScript. I see that your PHP code already converts to JSON, so you need to output the data in your PHP/HTML page like this:

```
<script>
var myData = '<?php echo $preguntas'; ?>;

console.log(myData.description);
</script>
```